# includeViewParams=true doesn't work in templated pages

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets, post-redirect-get

Consider this template:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
        <h:head>
            <title></title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:insert name="content"/>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

this page that uses it (/pages/test.xhtml):

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title></title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/testLayout.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="metadata">
                    <f:metadata>
                        <f:viewParam name="foobar" value="#{pageBean.foo}"/>
                    </f:metadata>
                </ui:define>
                <ui:define name="content">
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandLink value="Click"
                                       action="#{util.currentPageAction()}"/>
                    </h:form>
                </ui:define>
            </ui:composition>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

the page's bean:

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PageBean implements Serializable
{
    public String getFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    private String foo;
}
```

and this bean:

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Util implements Serializable
{
    public String currentPageAction()
    {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() +
                   "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
    }
}
```

When I load `http://localhost:8080/faces/pages/test.xhtml?foo=bar` in the browser and click the `<h:commandLink/>`, the URL changes to `http://localhost:8080/faces/pages/test.xhtml`. That is, the view parameters are not included in the redirect URL.

However, when I refactor the page such that it doesn't use a template, it behaves as expected. That is, the view parameters are included in the redirect URL.

I understand that `<f:metadata/>` doesn't and isn't supposed to work when placed inside a facelets template. This is not what's happening here, so it's a different issue. There's nothing in the spec to say that this can't be done. Indeed, there would be no other way (to my knowledge) to create a template-based page with view parameters.

Comment: Added comment to [this bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2260).

Comment: I hope this gets fixed some day. I voted for it.

Comment: I have a similar issue with an `<h:button />` or an `<h:link />` where including the attribute `includeViewParams="true"` doesn't yield the same behavior as repeating the view parameters using `<f:param />` entries.  When using `includeViewParams`, the parameter values in the link/GET request come from the `outcome` page's backing bean, rather than from the view parameters supplied to the current page as I believe they should be.  [Core JavaServer Faces - Third Edition](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/) p. 91 implies that these two methods should be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue,i resolve it as define "metadata" set Metadata gets injected right after f:view

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
   <f:metadata>
           <f:viewParam name="id" .../>
   </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>
```

template.xhtml

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xml:lang="en" lang="en">
         <f:view>
    <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
       <div id="container">
    <ui:insert name="content"/>
            </div>
          </f:view>
```